# Extracting DataView tables

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, data-export

I'm going to keep this high level as I've been trying to work out the best way of doing this for a while now.

I want to have the dataview tables in exacttarget extracted into my database (Postgres / Redshift) and want them kept as up to date as possible.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi is there no way to push more than six months data into data extension?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/95460)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use a SQL query on the data views you want to grab, which will push this information (last 6 months is all that is available) to a data extension.  From there you can do a data extract on the Data Extension and push it to an FTP from which you can grab it and push into your database via API call or something similar.

You can then put these into a scheduled automation in Automation Studio and have it run hourly, daily, weekly, etc.